# Make Socks 5 requires username / password authentication? Titanium web proxy

Tags: c#, titanium-web-proxy

How do users connect to SocksProxyEndPoint must authenticate username and password.

I have read that in the latest version of Titanium web proxy which allows to enable username password authentication when creating a SocksProxyEndPoint. But I don't know how to write that code and also can't find illustrative example, can someone help me do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic authentication, just set the `ProxyBasicAuthenticateFunc` property on the `ProxyServer` instance. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    var proxyServer = new ProxyServer();
    
    proxyServer.OnClientConnectionCreate += OnConnect;
    proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnBeforeRequest;
    
    var socksProxy = new SocksProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1080, false);
    
    proxyServer.ProxyBasicAuthenticateFunc = OnBasicAuth;
    
    proxyServer.AddEndPoint(socksProxy);
    proxyServer.Start();

    ...
}


public Task<bool> OnBasicAuth(SessionEventArgsBase ev, string u, string p) {
   if (u == "test" && p == "pass") {
       return Task.FromResult(true);
   }
   return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

Note that the data will be sent in plain text (no encryption). It could be acceptable in intranets, but if you allow public access to your proxy, either use a different authentication scheme (ProxySchemeAuthenticateFunc) or tunnel the traffic.